# WooCommerce: Get Product Variation ID By Matching Attributes

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

I want to get the variation id with respect to the mataching attribues with simple & optimized code.

```
function zx_get_variation( $product_id, $attributes )
{
    $CPT = new WC_Product_Data_Store_CPT();
    $variation_id = $CPT->find_matching_product_variation( new WC_Product($product_id), $attributes );

    return $variation_id;
}
```

This is returning "0"

But There is a matching variation avaiable.
[Variation Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZedW.png)

**Important:** I do not want to use `$product->get_available_variations()` as I do not want to use nested loop.

```
$products_object = [];
$attributes = [
    'attribute_pa_length'       => $filter_length, // term_slug
    'attribute_pa_material'     => $filter_type, // term_slug
    'attribute_pa_eye-type'     => $filter_material // term_slug
];

if( $products_2->have_posts() ):
    while( $products_2->have_posts() ): $products_2->the_post();

       $zx_product_var = zx_get_variation( get_the_ID(), $attributes );
        
        $product_ids[] = get_the_ID();
        $products_object[] = [
            'product_id'                => get_the_ID(),
            'product_title'             => get_the_title( get_the_ID() ),
            'product_price'             => get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_price', true ),
            'product_tax'               => get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'product_cat' )[0]->name,
            'product_sku'               => get_the_sku( get_the_ID() ),
            'post_date'                 => get_the_date( 'Ymd', get_the_ID() ),
            'product_thumbnail'         => wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id() ),
            'product_link'              => get_permalink(),
            'attribute_pa_length'       => $filter_length,
            'attribute_pa_eye_type'     => $filter_type,
            'attribute_pa_material'     => $filter_material,
            'variation_id'              => $zx_product_var,
        ];

    endwhile;
endif;
```